# Posting JSON to WCF RESTful API in System.Object not accepting it but Class accepts the input

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, wcf-rest

m sorry my Qs title is a bitt odd, i didnt found the right words to explain. Neways,

I have a WCF RESTful API in which I have implemented Custom Parameter Inspector class which inherits IParameterInspector to catch AfterCall and BeforeCall Methods.

```
public class CustomParameterInspector : IParameterInspector
{

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {}

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        // I have to perform certain tasks here
    }
}
```

now my service interface is like this

```
    [OperationContract]
    [CustomInspectorAttribute]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "GetMyDetail")]
    MyDetail GetMyDetail(MyDetail objMyDetail);
```

and service class is like this

```
public MyDetail GetMyDetail(MyDetail objMyDetail)
    {}
```

if I post **JSON** from client then it works fine.... in input[0] i get its type as **MyDetail**

But if change the input parameter to **Object** like this

```
[OperationContract]
    [CustomInspectorAttribute]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "GetMyDetail")]
    MyDetail GetMyDetail(Object objMyDetail);


public MyDetail GetMyDetail(Object objMyDetail)
    {}
```

then it does not gives me null in inputs[0] in BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)

Can you tell me y is this so and how can i solve it, I really need to get it in **object**

Comment: Why u want to change it into an object?

Comment: Do you mean you get a null when you change the type to object rather than MyDetail?

Comment: @Rajesh yes, that is the same scenerio

Comment: @Mark have to implement obfuscation..

Comment: That might make sense as the framework needs to know on how to deserialize the incoming request to the associated object. As an alternative you can implement a MessageInspector that does the deserialization of the incoming request and send it as an object to the method.